# Finding abundant numbers from 1 to 10 million using a sum

Tags: c, math, mathematical-optimization

My task is to implement algorithm in C of finding [abundant numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundant_number) from 1 to 10 million. Therefore I don't really understand mathematics.

There is several ways how to do it, but efficient and fast (for that BIG input 10 mil) might be by summing - NOT dividing, NOT multiplying, NOT EVEN using remainder after the division. Just sum.

But I'm really confused WHAT to sum. Please guys help, appreciate every single answer.

> Only I know is that there are 2476736 abundant numbers under 10
>   million, common computer hardware is not able to check it even in
>   hours, so I need more efficient algorithm and I know it's able to run
>   under a second.

Comment: Before asking for code, try to do the work yourself and post what you've tried and why it's not working as you think it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try this by counting all the multiples of an abundant number upto 10 million
suppose 12 is the first abundant number you found then 24 would definetly be abundant hence you can count all the multiples of 12 upto the limit you wish then go for the next number.I don't know how fast or efficient it would be.

Comment: Are u sure it works for all abundant numbers (every n-multiple of abundant number is also an abundant)?